# Data Modify Entity Problem 1.16.5

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Im trying to clone the inventory of one named storage to another.
I first tried finding a way to clone the inventory of a chest.

e.g:

```
execute as @e run data modify block[type=chest,name=input]...
```

But that didn't work because i couldn't because the block syntax only accepts xyz coordinates and not nbt data.

So i tried to do it with a chest Minecart using the data modify command which allow me to find my item through nbt selectors.

```
execute as @e run data modify entity @s[type=minecraft:chest_minecart,name=output] Items set from entity @s[type=minecraft:chest_minecart,name=input] Inventory
```

However for one reason or another I get no response at all.
Did I write this right or is there another way to do this.

Comment: I ran the following as a datapack and nothing happened I still didn't get the items clone in the first chest however I got output in chat of "[input] 1234"

    execute as @e run data modify entity @s[type=minecraft:chest_minecart,name="output"] Items set from entity @s[type=minecraft:chest_minecart,name="input"] Items
    execute as @e if entity @s[name="input"] run say 1234

Comment: Yes, one called input another called output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your original command does in Plain English:

> Tell all entities to, if they are a chest minecart named `output`, modify their `Items` tag to itself, only if they are also named `Input`.

That doesn't make sense. An entity can't be named both `input` and `output` at the same time. And, because you're using `@s` for both selectors in the `/data` command, the chest minecarts would be referring to themselves only to set the data, not any of the other chest minecarts.

So to fix this, try this approach:

```
execute as @e[type=chest_minecart,name=output] run data modify entity @s Items set from entity @e[type=chest_minecart,name=input,limit=1] Items
```